# choose one value multiple time in many to many field of Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i'm creating a Ecommerce website & i have a order item model which has many to many relationship with product model so customer can add products to their order. everything is okay with my system but the customer can't order one product twice or more since Many to many field choose an option once! how can i add one value twice in a many to many field?? also if you think there's a better way rather than using this system & many to many field, you can suggest!

```
#my_views_py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or str(self.id)


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product,blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Few changes in your existing code.

#my_views_py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or str(self.id)


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,blank=True)
    qty = models.CharField(null=False,blank=False)
    total_price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order)**strong text**

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem,blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Comment: i thought of this but when i make an order from the front end using react js, i find it difficult to post the order items one by one through fetch. i use Rest Api in backend! i have to use one fetch where the list of items will go one by one & make an OrderItem field, i didn't know how to do that which is why i choose this way